# Resolving port 5500 not free issue during Oracle 12c Release 2 Database Configuration Assistant installation on CentOS

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-12c, centos-7

**Background**

I am attempting to install Oracle 12c on CentOS 7 (deployed as a Hyper-V virtual machine) as outlined by this [installation guide](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Oracle12onCentos7).

**Problem**

Everything with my installation goes well except for the Oracle Database Configuration Assistant.

The installation provides me with the following messages:

1. `ACTION: Specify a free port`
2. `Action - Refer to the logs or contact Oracle Support Services.`

**Debuging Information and Actions Attempted**

When I run a tail on the error log I get the following messages related to the installation:

```
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: getting configAssistantParmas.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: checking secretArguments.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: starting read loop.
INFO: Read: [FATAL] [DBT-06103] The port (5,500) is already in use.
INFO: [FATAL] [DBT-06103] The port (5,500) is already in use.
WARNING: Skipping line: [FATAL] [DBT-06103] The port (5,500) is already in use.
INFO: Read:    ACTION: Specify a free port.
INFO:    ACTION: Specify a free port.
WARNING: Skipping line:    ACTION: Specify a free port.
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Database Configuration Assistant
```

Running `sudo netstat -anp | grep 550` returns the results below:

```
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37299    5502/gnome-pty-help
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37283    5501/gconfd-2
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     37287    5501/gconfd-2
```

To try and remedy the problem, prior to subsequent fresh installation attempts I commented out the following statements in my services file as displayed through running `cat /etc/services | grep 550`

```
new-rwho        550/tcp                 # new-who
new-rwho        550/udp                 # new-who
3m-image-lm     1550/tcp                # Image Storage license manager 3M Company
3m-image-lm     1550/udp                # Image Storage license manager 3M Company
ads             2550/tcp                # ADS
ads             2550/udp                # ADS
ssmpp           3550/tcp                # Secure SMPP
ssmpp           3550/udp                # Secure SMPP
gds-adppiw-db   4550/tcp                # Perman I Interbase Server
gds-adppiw-db   4550/udp                # Perman I Interbase Server
#fcp-addr-srvr1  5500/tcp                # fcp-addr-srvr1
#fcp-addr-srvr1  5500/udp                # fcp-addr-srvr1
#fcp-addr-srvr2  5501/tcp                # fcp-addr-srvr2
#fcp-addr-srvr2  5501/udp                # fcp-addr-srvr2
#fcp-srvr-inst1  5502/tcp                # fcp-srvr-inst1
#fcp-srvr-inst1  5502/udp                # fcp-srvr-inst1
#fcp-srvr-inst2  5503/tcp                # fcp-srvr-inst2
#fcp-srvr-inst2  5503/udp                # fcp-srvr-inst2
#fcp-cics-gw1    5504/tcp                # fcp-cics-gw1
#fcp-cics-gw1    5504/udp                # fcp-cics-gw1
checkoutdb      5505/tcp                # Checkout Database
checkoutdb      5505/udp                # Checkout Database
amc             5506/tcp                # Amcom Mobile Connect
amc             5506/udp                # Amcom Mobile Connect
fg-sysupdate    6550/tcp                # fg-sysupdate
fg-sysupdate    6550/udp                # fg-sysupdate
cloudsignaling  7550/udp                # Cloud Signaling Service
```

I have additionally attempted to do step 5.1 of the [installation guide](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Oracle12onCentos7) prior to the installation with no success.

**Screenshot**

[image: Installation Screen with Error Messages]

**Question**

Why am I getting an error that the port isn't open when it doesn't seem like anything is using that port and how to I remedy this issue?

Is there are method that can be used to change the port from 5500 to a complete different one? I'm just trying to get a dummy database installed for the HR schema.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered this exact error and found it was my mistake. Spent whole day for that.

Please, carefully observe your `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`.
In my case, "oem" was put in `/etc/hosts` and "eom" was in `/etc/hostname`.

Comment: I neglected specifying the host in the format `192.168.1.X host host.domain`. Adding the unqualified hostname fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, adding the unqualified hostname to /etc/hosts fixed my problem in RHEL 6.10.

Comment: I had the same problem. Adding the hostname into the /etc/hosts fixed this issue. See https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2277154_1.html for further information.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try adding your host to `/etc/hosts`.

I encountered the same error and the problem went away after I've done so.

See [Install Oracle Database 12c On CentOS7](https://www.unixmen.com/install-oracle-database-12c-centos-7/) by M.el Khamlichi.

Example from that link:

```
192.168.119.139 ora-c7.unixmen.local
```

Comment: Adding the host to `/etc/hosts` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*[Community Wiki](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) answer created from a comment left on the question:*</sub>

You can change the port for EM Express with `DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.SETHTTPPORT` and `DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.SETHTTPSPORT`. But EM Express is optional, you can just simply skip it. - [Balazs Papp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28019/balazs-papp)