# Oracle 12c Release 2 Database Configuration Assistant installation on CentOS - The port is already in use

Tags: oracle-12c

I know this error has already been intensively discussed in this thread here: [Resolving port 5500 not free issue during Oracle 12c Release 2 Database Configuration Assistant installation on CentOS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167384/resolving-port-5500-not-free-issue-during-oracle-12c-release-2-database-configur?newreg=edf12272a55b4ea4a8170e04ae94dd63)

However, despite the solutions proposed I can't install Oracle 12c on CentOS 7.

I skiped the Database Configuration Assistant during standard installation process in order to run it again using Xming. There it is possible to enter the `EM database express port` manually.

[image: Database Configuration Assistant]

I tried almost any port number, I always get the error message shown in the screenshot.

Do you have any suggestions what else I could do?

EDIT:

Content of /etc/hostname:

```
CentOS-Dev-db-12c.Company.local
```

Content of /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.10.113 CentOS-Dev-db-12c.Company.local
```

Comment: Please provide the contents of /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts

Comment: Are you using a shortened hostname at any point in the process? If you call the host CentOS-Dev-db-12c without the .Company.Local, this will not resolve.

Comment: Can you ping the hostname from the command prompt? ping CentOS-Dev-db-12c.Company.local

Comment: try including the shortened hostname in /etc/hosts e.g. 192.168.10.113 CentOS-Dev-db-12c.Company.local CentOS-Dev-db-12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle support doc **[DBT-06103] The port (5,500) is already in use. ACTION: Specify a free port (Doc ID 2277154.1)** says to put the unqualified hostname into /etc/hosts too. i.e:

```
192.168.10.113 CentOS-Dev-db-12c.Company.local CentOS-Dev-db-12c
```